# How to find the recurrence relation T(N) = T(N/2) + N^2

Tags: recurrence

What is the process that is involved in simplifying this recurrence relation?

I am able to get this much:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2
T(n) = T(n/4) + (n/2)^2 +n^2
T(n) = T(n/8) + (n/4)^2 + (n/2)^2 + n^2
```

I understand this will terminate when n = 1 because 1/2 = 0; C(0) = 0.
Past that I am stuck on a way to figure out these problems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths not computer programming.

Comment: I really don't get your point about 1/2 being 0. Should it really use integer division? If that is your real purpose, why don't just sum up all the values, e.g. C(5)=C(2)+5^2=C(1)+2^2+5^2=C(0)+1^2+2^2+5^2=30?

Answer (score 0):

Well the basic idea is that `C(N)` and `C(N/2)` should be an expression of the same form. Since their difference is a simple function of `N`, an infinite sum should pop to your mind, for which `C(N)-C(N/2)` becomes telescopic. Each term of the sum should be the given function with `N/2^k` (for `k=0, 1, ...`) as its argument.

Hence `C(N) = N^2 + (N/2)^2 + (N/4)^2 + (N/8)^2 + ...` does the job, and it can be further evaluated with the help of identities for geometric series as `C(N)=4/3*N^2`.

Comment: I answered a more generic question here, with the same example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674053/simplifying-recurrence-relation-cn-cn-2-n2/22675310#22675310