# Simplifying Recurrence Relation c(n) = c(n/2) + n^2

Tags: math, relation, recurrence

I'm really confused on simplifying this recurrence relation: c(n) = c(n/2) + n^2.

So I first got:

c(n/2) = c(n/4) + n^2
so
c(n) = c(n/4) + n^2 + n^2
c(n) = c(n/4) + 2n^2

c(n/4) = c(n/8) + n^2
so
c(n) = c(n/8) + 3n^2

I do sort of notice a pattern though:

2 raised to the power of whatever coefficient is in front of "n^2" gives the denominator of what n is over.

I'm not sure if that would help.

I just don't understand how I would simplify this recurrence relation and then find the theta notation of it.

EDIT: Actually I just worked it out again and I got c(n) = c(n/n) + n^2*lgn.

I think that is correct, but I'm not sure. Also, how would I find the theta notation of that? Is it just theta(n^2lgn)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math and it belongs to [Math.SE]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure to **substitute** `n/2` everywhere `n` appears in the original recurrence relation when placing `c(n/2)` on the lhs.

i.e.

```
c(n/2) = c(n/4) + (n/2)^2
```

Your intuition is correct, in that it is a very important part of the problem. How many times can you divide `n` by `2` before we reach `1`?

Let's take 8 for an example

```
8/2 = 4
4/2 = 2
2/2 = 1
```

You see it's `3`, which as it turns out is `log(8)`

In order to prove the theta notation, it might be helpful to check out the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). This is a very useful tool for proving complexity of a recurrence relation.

Using the master theorem case 3, we can see

```
a = 1
b = 2
logb(a) = 0
c = 2
n^2 = Omega(n^2)
k = 9/10
(n/2)^2 < k*n^2
c(n) = Theta(n^2)
```

The intuition as to why the answer is `Theta(n^2)` is that you have `n^2 + (n^2)/4 + (n^2)/16 + ... + (n^2)/2^(2n)`, which won't give us `logn` `n^2`s, but instead increasingly smaller `n^2`s

Comment: Would it then be c(n) = c(n/n) + n^2*lgn?

Comment: @user3421510 see my updated answer working out case 3 of the master theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's answer a more generic question for recurrences of the form:
`r(n) = r(d(n)) + f(n)`. There are some restrictions for the functions, that need further discussion, e.g. if `x` is a fix point of `d`, then `f(x)` should be 0, otherwise there isn't any solution. In your specific case this condition is satisfied.

Rearranging the equation we get that `r(n) - r(d(n)) = f(n)`, and we get the intuition that `r(n)` and `r(d(n))` are both a sum of some terms, but `r(n)` has one more term than `r(d(n))`, that's why the `f(n)` as the difference. On the other hand, `r(n)` and `r(d(n))` have to have the same 'form', so the number of terms in the previously mentioned sum has to be infinite.

Thus we are looking for a telescopic sum, in which the terms for `r(d(n))` cancel out all but one terms for `r(n)`:

```
  r(n)    = f(n) + a_0(n) + a_1(n) + ...
- r(d(n)) =      - a_0(n) - a_1(n) - ...
```

This latter means that

```
  r(d(n)) =        a_0(n) + a_1(n) + ...
```

And just by substituting `d(n)` into the place of `n` into the equation for `r(n)`, we get:

```
  r(d(n)) = f(d(n)) + a_0(d(n)) + a_1(d(n)) + ...
```

So by choosing `a_0(n) = f(d(n))`, `a_1(n) = a_0(d(n)) = f(d(d(n)))`, and so on: `a_k(n) = f(d(d(...d(n)...)))` (with `k+1` pieces of `d` in each other), we get a correct solution.

Thus in general, the solution is of the form `r(n) = sum{i=0..infinity}(f(d[i](n)))`, where `d[i](n)` denotes the function `d(d(...d(n)...))` with `i` number of iterations of the `d` function.

For your case, `d(n)=n/2` and `f(n)=n^2`, hence you can get the solution in closed form by using identities for geometric series. The final result is `r(n)=4/3*n^2`.

Answer (score 0):

Go for advance Master Theorem.

```
T(n) = aT(n/b)+n^klog^p

where a>0 b>1 k>0 p=real number.

case 1: a>b^k

         T(n) = 0(n^logba)  b is in base.
case 2 a=b^k

 1. p>-1 T(n)  than T(n)=0(n^logba log^p+1)
 2. p=-1 Than T(n)=0(n^logba logn)
 3. p<-1 than T(n)=0(n^logba)

case 3: a<b^k

 1.if p>=0 than T(n)=0(n^k log^p n)
 2 if p<0 than T(n)=O(n^k)
```

forgave Constant bcoz constant doesn't change time complexity or constant change processor to processor .(i.e n/2 ==n*1/2 == n)